# Not able to read cookie on JS side on Safari/iPhone

Tags: javascript, angular, http, cookies, safari

Here is the workflow :

- I send an e-mail to a customer. This mail contains a link to my Angular application : `acme.com?token=abcd`
- The user clicks on the link in the mail and is redirected to my application.
- A GET request is done. This response headers contains a `Set-Cookie XSRF:12345`
- Then, after the GET response, a POST request is done, supposedly using the previous XSRF token.

**Problem** : on Safari/iPhone (and *only* on Safari/iPhone, it works on Safari/Mac), the cookie is not visible on JS side.

As a reminder, the XSRF cookie is intended to be read in JS and reinjected in the HTTP headers of subsequent POST/PUT/DELETE requests. As a result, the `POST` request is sent without the XSRF header (but with the XSRF cookie) and ends with a 403 error. Everything works as if the cookie was `HttpOnly`, but it's not !

Here is the full detail of the `Set-cookie` :

```
Set-Cookie: XSRF=[...]; Expires=Thu, 23-Apr-2020 16:07:10 GMT; Path=/;SameSite=Strict;Secure
```

I suspected problems with the `SameSite` policy because the user comes on the website after clicking on a link in an e-mail. So, I tried adding a rebound : after clicking, the user now lands on a `acme.com/redirect.html?token=abcd` page that redirects to `acme.com?token=abcd` (via `window.location.href=...`)

As a matter of fact, it works... but I don't understand **why**. If it was a problem of `SameSite`, why would the `XSRF` cookie still be sent ? And, as it is not marked as `HttpOnly`, why can't I read it on JS side ? Is there a way on Safari to investigate why the cookie is rejected ? Also, I found that some versions of Safari might have some bugs with cookie handling. Is there a way to deactivate SameSite policy on Safari/iPhone in order to understand if it comes from there ?

Comment: It seems I'm stuck on something similar. Have you found some answers to your questions?

Comment: @DanielStucki it is not clear if it is a bug or a feature but you cannot read even non-Http-Only cookies from JS if you come from a third-party app to Safari : https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=208049 That is why it works with the rebound. Because of the rebound, the user is not seen as coming from a third party app anymore.

Comment: Also, some combinations of `Secure` and `SameSite=Lax` can prevent from setting a cookie in a cross domain context. But when this is the case, there is an explicit  warning in the console.

Comment: Strange enough I'm not in a cross domain context. Easened my non-Http-Only Cookie from SameSite: strict to lax and it's working for me now. Found through your webkit bug link and finally landing on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55937018/previously-set-samesite-strict-cookie-not-available-in-document-cookie-firefo?rq=1